My website suddenly asks me "This site asks for consent to use your data" [screenshot included]
My website is almost coded one by one word by myself. I only used smarty, jquery and some other old libs. I didn't change the code for years.
Today when I opened my site, it suddenly asked "This site asks for consent to use your data", which I have no idea what it is.

That's definitely not my code. I immediately check my VPS and all files are as the same as my local backup, means my files didn't get hacked.
More detail:

I only save cookies for setting about the language and platform(desktop/mobile).
I use Cloudflare as CDN
I may have adsbygoogle.js included in my page but it never worked. I never saw a google ad on my site.

What causes this pop up? Is it Cloudflare or Google adsense or something else?

This is the consent form from Google AdSense that Google has enabled for you to comply with regulations. Log into Google AdSense go to Privacy and messaging, look under Consent management solutions. One of the auto generated consent forms will be enabled.

If your website suddenly started asking for consent to use data, so likely due to recent changes on privacy regulations or updates in browser policies regarding the use of cookies and tracking technologies.

You can check you cookies usage.
Check cloudflare configuration regarding cookies settings.
You can check google ads configuration as well.

